# Alternative to attempting to persist Environment Variables in Python

Tags: python, oauth, environment-variables, access-token

Up until now, whenever I have needed to store a "secret" for a simple python application, I have relied on environment variables.  In Windows, I set the variables via the Computer Properties dialog and I access them in my Python code like this:

```
database_password = os.environ['DB_PASS']
```

The simplicity of this approach has served me well. Now I have a project that uses Oauth2 authentication and I have a need to store tokens to the environment that may change throughout program execution.  I want them to persist the next time I execute the program.  This is what I have come up with:

```
#fetch a new token
token = oauth.fetch_token('https://api.example.com/oauth/v2/token', code=secretcode)
access_token = token['access_token']

#make sure it persists in the current session
os.environ['TOKEN'] = access_token

#store to the system environment (Windows)
cmd = 'SETX /M TOKEN ' + access_token
os.system(cmd)
```

It gets the job done quickly for me today, but does not seem like the right approach to add to my toolbox.  Does anyone have a more elegant way of doing what I am trying to do that does not add too many layers of complexity? If the solution worked across platforms that would be a bonus.

Comment: I find it easy to just use a json file to store your token or passwords. If you have 20 different tokens or database pwd you will have that many environment variables. But with a josn, you will have a nice dictionary structure where you name your keys properly and accordingly. Simply read json and retrieve data. Reading and writing to json files should not be too complex

Comment: You could look into using [temporary files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) or the [Registry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) (Windows only of course).

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Thanks. Do you encrypt the file or the variables within it in any way?

Comment: yea I just use the cryptography module to encrypt my stuff. I generate a key and that key can be stored anywhere or even as an environment variable. One key for all isn't too safe but it's safe nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the Python [keyring](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring) module with great success. It's an interface to credential vaults provided by the operating system (e.g., Windows Credential Manager). I haven't used it on Linux, but it appears to be supported, as well.

Storing a password/token and then retrieving it can be as simple as:

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("system", "username", "password")
keyring.get_password("system", "username")
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to transfer the credentials between computers?

Comment: @ricoflow, could you elaborate on your use case?

There certainly doesn't seem to be anything baked in to _keyring_ that is meant for syncing credentials between multiple machines.

Comment: I will typically do the development of a python script on my computer.  When it is ready for testing on another user's machine or a server, I will push it up to GitHub.  When I pull down the code on the target machine, all I have to worry about is manually updating the environment variables for any database connections, etc.  It looks like Windows Credential Manager can be exported/imported from one machine to another, but from what I have read it does not seem like passwords can be moved on a per-password basis, only as the entire set.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the native Windows functionality only provides a bulk export/import capability. The _keyring_ module could be used to selectively extract credentials from the Windows Credential Locker on your development machine and then (after a file transfer) another Python script on the server could use _keyring_ to insert those passwords into the server's Credential Locker.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a third-party backend for keyring available called [keyrings.cryptfile](https://pypi.org/project/keyrings.cryptfile). Presumably it maintains all of your keyring credentials in a single file. _Might_ be able to just file copy that cryptfile to the server.